# Do Akai masterkeyboards work with LMMS?

Tags: hardware, lmms

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to buy a usb masterkeyboard [(Akai LPK 25)](http://www.thomann.de/de/akai_lpk_25.htm) to work with it in Linux Multimedia Studio (LMMS).
My questions are:

1. Has anyone experiences with this or similar masterkeyboards?
2. Do they even work with LMMS?
3. If yes, do they work plug-and-play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my basic understanding of German and Google translate, I come to the following conclusion: yes, this keyboard will function basically if not completely with LMMS.

On the site, you can see that the keyboard contains its own USB-MIDI interface, and assuming you're using ALSA, you'll be able to plug-and-play out of the box forwarding notes to and from the keyboard.

Bonus functions like the tap tempo buttons may not function at first, but assuming it's a standard, it shouldn't take much Googling to make it work like it should under Ubuntu or other Linux Distro.

The software provided of course likely will not work, but should be emulate-able using WINE.

Yes, this keyboard will work with LMMS.